# Hosted Authorization Server does not redirect to localhost client

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-security

So I have followed the guide [here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) to implement a Spring Authorization Server. I have managed to get both a client and server ready for testing. The reason why I need and authorization server is because I need to be able to authenticate multiple microservices that work together.

I have run both the server and client on my machine. The authorization server at `localhost:9999` and the client at `localhost:8080/client` (setting the client app context-path to /client). The authentication for the client works perfectly in this scenario. To make this easy, I decided to host the authorization server on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk. For secrecy, I will use SERVER_URL as the hosted authorization server's URL.

Once the server is hosted, I run the client using the hosted authorization server with the correct token and authorization URLs. Once I go to `localhost:8080`, I get redirected to SERVER_URL where the homepage displays a link to Google OAuth login. Clicking on that link takes me to google login and I login with my google account. After the google login, it redirects back to `SERVER_URL/login?code=the_code&state=the_state`. This is is not what I want. After logging into Google, the user should be redirected back to `localhost:8080/login?code=the_code&state=the_state`.

I have been researching for days but cannot seem to find a solution to this problem. I need to be able to test multiple microservices on localhost with the hosted server.

My authorization server main application class is the default (I haven't added anything). Here is my security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Order(200)
public class OAuthSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final String GOOGLE_LOGIN_FILTER = "/login/google";

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("google")
    public ClientResources google() {
        return new ClientResources();
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {
        return ssoFilter(google(), GOOGLE_LOGIN_FILTER);
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter googleFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(GOOGLE_LOGIN_FILTER);
        OAuth2RestTemplate googleTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
        googleFilter.setRestTemplate(googleTemplate);

        UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(), client.getClient().getClientId());
        tokenServices.setRestTemplate(googleTemplate);
        googleFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);

        return googleFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter> oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter>();
        registration.setFilter(filter);
        registration.setOrder(-100);
        return registration;
    }

    /**
     * Specify the authorization criteria for request access.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .csrf()
            .disable();
    }

}

class ClientResources {
    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails client = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private ResourceServerProperties resource = new ResourceServerProperties();

    public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public ResourceServerProperties getResource() {
        return resource;
    }
}
```

Then I have a separate class for protecting the "/me" path:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/me")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
    }

}
```

And my `application.yml` for the auth server:

```
spring:
    mvc:
        view:
            prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
            suffix: .jsp

server:
    port: ${PORT:9999}
    error:
        whitelabel:
            enabled: false

security:
    oauth2:
        client:
            client-id: google client id
            client-secret: google client secret
            scope: read,write
            auto-approve-scopes: '.*'

google:
    client:
        clientId: google client id
        clientSecret: google client secret
        accessTokenUri: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
        userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
        clientAuthenticationScheme: form
        scope:
            - openid
            - profile
            - email
    resource:
        userInfoUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
        preferTokenInfo: true
```

The controller for "/me" path is trivial, so I am not going to include that here. And yes, I am using the same google client id and secret for Google and the server itself (for now).

Now on my client side, the `application.yml`:

```
authorization-server-url: SERVER_URL

security:
    oauth2:
        client:
            clientId: google client id
            clientSecret: google client secret
            accessTokenUri: ${authorization-server-url}/oauth/token
            userAuthorizationUri: ${authorization-server-url}/oauth/authorize
        resource:
            userInfoUri: ${authorization-server-url}/me
```

And the security configuration on my client side uses @Configurable, @EnableWebSecurity, and @EnableOAuth2SSO. The security configuration prevents access of unauthenticated users, which is why as soon as I go on localhost:8080, it redirects me to the auth server.

The auth server, when used by itself, successfully logs into google. And if the client application at localhost:8080 is configured to authenticate with Google OAuth directly instead of the custom auth server, then it does that successfully. The problem is the proper redirect after the auth server has logged in with Google.

Just to clarify, I am after the flow `localhost:8080` -> auth server -> click link which takes you to `SERVER_URL/login/google` -> Login with Google -> `localhost:8080`. But what I'm getting is `localhost:8080` -> auth server -> click link which takes you to `SERVER_URL/login/google` -> Login with Google -> `SERVER_URL/login?code=the_code&state=the_s`tate.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Here is my gradle configuration:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'

group = this is a secret
version = '0.0.4-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.SR1'
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2')
    implementation('javax.servlet:jstl')
    implementation('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

The error page I get is at the url `http://<SERVER_URL>/login?code=xgYiHr&state=Wp1SUW` where `<SERVER_URL>` is the domain name of the authorization server. And I get the following error page:

[image: Error Page]

And the Network traffic for the error page. According to this, `http://<SERVER_URL>/oauth/authorize` has the correct `redirect_uri` which is `http://localhost:8080/login`, but when it comes to redirecting to it the `localhost:8080` url gets replaced with `<SERVER_URL>`:

[image]

Funny thing is, I just tried running the client application through `http://127.0.0.1:8080` instead of `http://localhost:8080` and it works perfectly! Not sure why `localhost:8080` gets replaced by the `<SERVER_URL>`. I'm not sure if this problem is with AWS or Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I was right in thinking there is something wrong with my AWS setup. I changed the environment in Elastic Beanstalk to use Nginx as the Proxy server, which solved my issue. Now I can test my client using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`.